# How to make a picture that follow the mouse movement?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a window application in C# 2.0.
I have a picture that I already added as a reference for the project.

The thing I can't do is this:
I need the picture to move after the mouse movement,it means that next to the mouse's sign on the screen there will be my picture to move with it.

I suppose that I should use the function of `MouseMove`, but I can't see exactly how.

Any help would be useful :) 
ThanKs!

Comment: Like Yads asked, or did you mean anywhere on the screen - even outside your WinForms? In that case you'll need to use the Win32 API if you're working on Windows, if you're using MONO I have no idea how to accomplish the above.

Comment: I'm using winForms, and my picture is being saved as a Bitmap format.

Answer (score 2):

In order to save the Bitmap to a picture box so it is displayed, you could simply set it as follows:

```
this.pictureBox.Image = yourBitmapImage;
```

To set the `MouseMove` function, right click on the form in VisualStudios and go to properties. Depending on your version, you might see a lightning bolt in the little window. Then you can define or assign the `MouseMove` function similar to what Gabe said.

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.pictureBox1.Location = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
}
```

If you have code with the argument as an `EventArgs e`, you can cast it as a `MouseEventArg` as follows:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var me = (MouseEventArgs)e;
    this.pictureBox1.Location = new Point(me.X, me.Y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle `MouseMove` event and change picture location on form according new mouse location.

Comment: How can I change a location of a Bitmap? I had to use this format and I can't see at is properties a location...

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   this.pictureBox1.Location = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
}
```

Comment: My picture is in a BitMap format,is there any easy way to convert it so I could use a pictureBox for my picture in my program?  It seems like regular conversion in the code doesn't work...